# How to log sql script on try catch

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a scenario  SaveChanges();  failed for two sql script ,is that possible to log sql script in catch method ?
EX add method :- _sqlDb.Deleted.Add(deleted);

```
catch (DbOperationException ex)
               { 
               //something here 
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a own written sql statement you could use a variable declared outside of try/catch

```
string sql = string.Empty;
try
{
  // build your sql statement, ie:
  sql = "SELECT * FROM <table>";
  // execute statement
}
catch(Excepction ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  Console.WriteLine(sql);
}
```

Comment: my case not like this i have 2 scripts before savechanges . in exception i want to log which one